# Xamarin forms Http web request

Tags: rest, xamarin.forms, get, httpwebrequest

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project and in the project I have to GET data from a Json URL, I'm using this code :

```
 string URL = "https://example.com/.json";
   var httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
   var response = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
   var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
   var firebasevariable = JObject.Parse(stream);
   string dist = firebasevariable["distance"].ToObject<string>();
```

but the "dist" value keeps returning NULL ! I imported the System.Net.Http and the Newtonsoft.Json libraries
I also get this warning but I don't know if its the cuz why I get the NULL , I tried my link using the postman and it returns the data perfectly

> There was a conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"

Comment: have you verified that `stream` contains valid JSON?

Comment: @Jason , yes the JSON is 100% valid , I tried another code but it also return's a NULL [ HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string response = await client.GetStringAsync("https:/example.com/.json");

            var variables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myclass>(response); ]

Comment: try `firebasevariable.Value<string>("distance");`  if that doesn't work, you need to inspect `firebasevariable` with the debugger

Comment: @Jason i tried it but it didnt work then i tried to debug the code and i found out that the response from the JSON is already NULL , I don't know why since i tried the link with postman and its returning a valid data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Firebase too and this is working:

```cs
async Task<string> Get(string url)
{
    using(var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        // Client is a static HttpClient property. 
        // It's recommended to use a single instance in all your requests, but create it in this method if you want.
        var response = await Client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        var contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return contentString;
        else
            throw new Exception(contentString);
    }
}
```

This method will, of course, return a JSON string. After getting it, you can deserialize it to whatever you want.

If the exception is thrown, it probably means authentication issues (just read what `contentString` says). If it returns correctly but the value is null, then probably you are using a different URL from your Postman tests and the path's value on the database is really null.

Hope it helps!

Comment: you are a real lifesaver ! , it worked perfectly , do you know how can I keep updating the result every one sec or two ? cuz the database I'm working with keep's updating the values every one sec , I tried to add a while loop but it didn't work

Comment: Glad to help! About your question, I really wouldn't recommend doing this in a large scale, it will be pretty expensive when the user base starts to grow. My recommendation is: if you are using Firebase Realtime Database, you can use "FirebaseDatabase.net", a library for Xamarin.Forms that has Realtime updates; if you are using Firestore and your app is only for iOS and Android, you can use the native Firestore libraries (it will be a little more complex); and if you target more than these two platforms, then you'll have to use a loop as Firestore doesn't have RESTful realtime updates yet.

Comment: If you either are on the last category that I spoken of and really can't use the native Realtime functionality of Firebase or your project will not be used by a lot of users and you think you don't need to worry about database calls, then I suggest you open another question on SO with the details of this loop that didn't work (because my method should have worked inside a loop :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! , this is the kind of information I was looking for , you've summarized the whole thing